# Adding a rust file to a cargo project in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, module, rust-cargo

After executing the command `cargo new main`, I proceeded to include additional files in the project, which were placed under the src/ directory. During this process, Visual Studio Code presented me with the following notification:

[image]

It seems that unless I click 'yes', I am unable to utilize the mod ; syntax for these files. I would appreciate a clear explanation of what happens when I click 'yes' (and why this action isn't performed automatically). Furthermore, I would like to know how to handle files that I did not add.

Comment: What is your project structure? What is in Cargo.toml?

Comment: Do you have the right folder opened as a workspace?

Comment: What file do you have open?

Comment: @BallpointBen Thanks! I opened vscode one level up in the file system. I didn't thought it would cause problems but it was indeed that.

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add transcriptions** of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting).

Comment: Are you trying to add a new rust file other than main.rs?

Answer (score 0):

After executing `cargo new main` the `main` folder is created and you should open it with the following option.

This way Rust analyzer will not prompt the notification.

[image: Open Folder image]